# Django: find the id with a value_list

Tags: python, django

How do you find the id of a value_list

Here is what I have:

views.py:

```
        group = Groups_By_Dates.objects.filter(date=date)

        all_groups = group.values_list('time', flat=True)

        time = Groups_By_Dates.objects.get(time=???)
```

I need to be able find time so that I can use it later in my template for a url. How would I be able to do that?

I have tried doing that already but it doesn't work:

```
{% for grouptime in all_groups %}
    <div class="row1">
        <a href='{% url "listbygroup" time.id %}'> {{grouptime}}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">

    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `time` is a single `GroupByDates` object? What if multiple ons exist? After all `all_groups` is a *list* of `id`s.

Comment: yes and Groups_By_Dates.objects.get(time=all_groups) doesn't work. This is what I get in return: The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

Comment: well that is logical, you can try to use `time__in=all_groups`, but this looks like simply wrong modeling. You have no guarantees whatsoever that there is only one `Groups_By_Dates`, so this can raise a `MultipleObjectsReturned` error.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
times = Groups_By_Dates.objects.filter(time_id__in=Groups_By_Dates.objects.filter(date=date).values('time'))
time = times.first()
```